# Print each row with a different color PHP

Tags: php, html, colors

So i'm exploring PHP and working on a web app. I display a table from my database. However, i want each row to be displayed in a different color.
For example: row1 in green; row2 in blue; row3 in grey... And so on!

Here's my code:

```
<?php

$username = 'root';
$pwd = '';
$db_name = 'fileattente';

$db = new mysqli('localhost', $username, $pwd, $db_name) or die("Unable to connect.");
?>


<table>
<tr>
<th><span class="Style1">SERVICE</span> </th>
<th><span class="Style2">NUMERO</span></th>
<th><span class="Style3">GUICHET</span></th>
<th><span class="Style4">EN ATTENTE</span></th>
</tr>


<?php

$req_service_1="SELECT `LIBESERV`, `CODESERV`, `CODEGUIC` , `NOMBATTE` FROM `v_attente_service`";
$stid1= mysqli_query($db, $req_service_1);
while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($stid1)) 
{ 
?>
<!--While true, do the following-->
    <tr>
    <td  class="Style14"><span>
    <?php echo $row['LIBESERV'];?>
    </span></td>
<td><?php echo $row['CODESERV'];?>  </td>   
<td><blink><?php echo $row['CODEGUIC'];?></blink></td>
<td><?php echo $row['NOMBATTE'];?></td>

<?php
} //End of while loop
?>
```

Already looked through some other similar questions here, but they alternate 2 colors between rows, and that is not what i want.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So alternate between any number of colors. Create array of colors and use it.

Comment: @u_mulder how do i do that please? I am still learning PHP, thank you so much!

Comment: why not use a random color generator with `rand(0,255);`

Comment: @Baklap4 the colors i want to display are not random! Each row is color coded!

Comment: @jungkookie alright didn't get that from your question. Then the answer u_mulder have given you does it's job!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code

```
<?php

$username = 'root';
$pwd = '';
$db_name = 'fileattente';

$db = new mysqli('localhost', $username, $pwd, $db_name) or die("Unable to connect.");
?>
<table>
  <tr>
   <th><span class="Style1">SERVICE</span> </th>
   <th><span class="Style2">NUMERO</span></th>
   <th><span class="Style3">GUICHET</span></th>
   <th><span class="Style4">EN ATTENTE</span></th>
  </tr>

<?php
  $req_service_1="SELECT `LIBESERV`, `CODESERV`, `CODEGUIC` , `NOMBATTE` FROM `v_attente_service`";
  $stid1= mysqli_query($db, $req_service_1);
  $records = mysqli_fetch_array($stid1)
  $colors = array('red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow', 'black');
  for($i=0; $i<$count($records); $i++){
  ?>
    <tr style="background-color: <?php echo $colors[$i]; ?>">
      <td><span><?php echo $row['LIBESERV'];?></span></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['CODESERV'];?></td>   
      <td><blink><?php echo $row['CODEGUIC'];?></blink></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['NOMBATTE'];?></td>
    </tr>
  <?php
  }
  ?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I finally get the result i want!! This code works!

Comment: one of these days i will paint my room a nice, bright `Undefined offset`.

Answer (score 4):

Here's some simple code that will show different `$cur_color` on each iteration:

```
$colors = array('red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow', 'black');
$i = 0;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($stid1)) {
    $cur_color = $colors[$i % count($colors)];
    echo '$cur_color is ' . $cur_color;
    $i++;
}
```

Just add `$cur_color` to the style of your `tr/td`.

Comment: It should work, but it is not... I added the following: <td style= $cur_color> is it correct?

Comment: As already mentioned `style='color:red'` or `style='background-color:red'`

Answer (score 0):

Try echo like this

```
<?php

 $colors = Array("bfbfbf","cccc","fbfbff","00ffff","bffbff");

$x = 0;

while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($stid1)) 
{ 

  if(!isset($colors[$x])){
      $x = 0; //if color will less then records it will start from 0 again
   }

echo "<tr>
  <td style='color:#".$colors[$x]."'><span>".$row['LIBESERV']."</span></td>
  <td style='color:#".$colors[$x]."'>".$row['CODESERV']."</td>   
  <td style='color:#".$colors[$x]."'><blink>".$row['CODEGUIC']."</blink></td>
  <td style='color:#".$colors[$x]."'>."$row['NOMBATTE']."</td> 

   </tr>";


$x++;
}


?>
```

Comment: And where are different colors?

Comment: @Dest - repeating the question's title: "Print each row with a different color PHP"...

Comment: @Dest , yes! that is what i want!!

Comment: @Dest yes, your answer now conforms to my question, thank you! ^^

Answer (score 0):

This PHP code will generate a table with rainbow colors:

```
<?php
function hue2rgb($t)
{
    if ($t < 0) $t += 1;
    if ($t > 1) $t -= 1;
    if ($t < 1/6) return 6 * $t;
    if ($t < 1/2) return 1;
    if ($t < 2/3) return (2/3 - $t) * 6;
    return 0;
}
function color_hex($hue)
{
    return sprintf('#%02x%02x%02x',
        round(255 * hue2rgb($hue + 1/3)),
        round(255 * hue2rgb($hue)),
        round(255 * hue2rgb($hue - 1/3))
    );
}

$rows = 100;
?>
<table style="width:100%">
<?php for ($i = 0; $i < $rows; $i++):?>
    <tr style="background:<?=color_hex($i / $rows)?>">
        <td>Row <?=$i + 1?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endfor?>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

Technique #1

```
<?php 

$rand = array('0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f');
$color = '#'.$rand[rand(0,15)].$rand[rand(0,15)].$rand[rand(0,15)].$rand[rand(0,15)].$rand[rand(0,15)].$rand[rand(0,15)];

?>
```

Then echo out the $color value anywhere you need it. For example:

```
<body style="background: <?php echo $color; ?>;">
```

Technique #2

```
<?php printf( "#%06X\n", mt_rand( 0, 0xFFFFFF )); ?>
```

My favorite one is:

```
<?php  $color = sprintf("%02x%02x%02x", mt_rand(0x22, 0xaa), mt_rand(0x22, 0xaa), mt_rand(0x22, 0xaa)); ?>
```

Source: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/php/random-hex-color/