# How to display each row with a different color

Tags: php, html, css

I am new to PHP and I want to display a table from my database with each row with a different color from other rows and I tried answers and solutions similar to my question but I failed to make it done on the rows of `<td><?= $field ?></td>`

This my script :

```
<?php
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$mysqli = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','class');
$mysqli->query("set names 'UTF8'");

$data = [];
$res = $mysqli->query("SELECT math, physics, english FROM student order by math desc");
while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
    foreach(array_keys($row) as $key) {
        $data[$key][] = $row[$key];
    }
}

?>

<div>student</div>
<table border="1">
  <?php foreach($data as $key => $val): ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?= $key ?></td>
      <?php foreach($val as $field): ?>
        <td><?= $field ?></td>
      <?php endforeach ?>
    </tr>
  <?php endforeach ?>
</table>
```

Comment: The [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399137/easiest-way-to-alternate-row-colors-in-php-html) I posted was more a case of alternate rows rather than a different color in each row.

Comment: After how many records should the colours repeat? If you had 16,700,001 records admittedly the universe might have ended before the browser rendered the recordset but ... ??

Comment: @RamRaider I am just learning PHP I want for example first row of math ,physics ,english to be yellow and second row in a different color just to make the differance visible I want something like this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37810338/print-each-row-with-a-different-color-php) but for my problem .

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the help of CSS

For even and odd selectors you follow following syntax

```
table tr:nth-child(even) td{
   background: #f1f1f1;
}
table tr:nth-child(odd) td{
   background: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm just using the following function as an example which returns a random color. The function has been posted by [@outis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9901154/3963382)

```
function rand_color() {
  return '#' . str_pad(dechex(mt_rand(0, 0xFFFFFF)), 6, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
}
```

This will return a random RGB hex string which you can use in your foreach loop, like this (note the `<tr>` tag):

```
<div>student</div>
 <table border="1">
   <?php foreach($data as $key => $val): ?>
   echo '<tr style="background-color:' . rand_color() .   '">';
     <td><?= $key ?></td>
      <?php foreach($val as $field): ?>
     <td><?= $field ?></td>
   <?php endforeach ?>
   </tr>
   <?php endforeach ?>
 </table>
</div>
```

If you just want to use specifiek colors, then i suggest to define those colors in an array, and then use those as you loop through your data.

Comment: Sir thanks for you replay , your solution did not work for me probably because I am just learning PHP and I could not figure out how to use it but how can I have specific colors using array I tried this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37810338/print-each-row-with-a-different-color-php) but the result I get was just one color in all rows so  How can I use the idea for this answer on my problem to get specific colors and thanks for your help .